# Deploying Open Source Projects to Maven Central Repository

Tags: maven-central

I had a maven project which I successfully deployed to Sonatype.
All the checks were successful.So,I released it from Sonatype.
But even though Maven Central Sync has been activated,the project I released is not yet been released to Maven Central Repository.

Can anyone please suggest solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The artifacts should be published to central in 10-15 minutes, but it can take up to several hours before you'll see them in the search results at https://search.maven.org.

If it's been longer than that file an issue at https://issues.sonatype.org in the "Community Support - Maven Central" and we'll look into this for you.